# Php: Sonar error Review the data-flow - use of uninitialized value

Tags: php, sonarqube

I have this code that Sonar shows a bug in it, how to solve it?

```
public function __construct($terminal_code, $user, $user_profile_level, $params = null, $loadOldData = true) {
    // get conection
    $this->conn = getStrDsn();

    
    // set variables
    $this->terminal_code = strtoupper(trim($terminal_code));
    $this->user_id = strtoupper(trim($user_id));

**Review the data-flow - use of uninitialized value.**
    

    $this->user_profile_level = $user_profile_level;
 ... another code
}
```

Comment: Please show the whole class. Did you initialize `$user_profile_level` in the class and when creationg an object from the class, do you provide something in the third paramter `$user_profile_level` like `new YourClass(1, 2, 3);`

Comment: it's a huge class, but yeah its initialize : class CriticalFieldsClass {
    public $user_profile_level; it has no initial value